# Unable to author block in slot 270671004,. `can_author_with` returned: `spec_name` does not match

Tags: frontier

I have changed the name on my spec.json and I am getting this erro

```
Unable to author block in slot 270671004,. `can_author_with` returned: `spec_name` does not match `X` vs `node-frontier-template` Probably a node update is required!

Edit :
```

I have changed this too !

```
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("x"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("x"),
    authoring_version: 1,
    spec_version: 1,
    impl_version: 1,
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    transaction_version: 1,
    state_version: 1,
};
```

What would be the issue behind?

Answer (score 1):

Take Polkadot as an example.

You can not change the spec name in runtime [lib.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/00f873119c8491a5d188d5aa3050035180f7e5e3/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L112), nor the one in spec file [polkadot.json](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/chain-specs/polkadot.json) during the chain is running.

---

IIUC, if you want to change it, you need to start a new chain. Otherwise, you might need to do a lot of extra work.

Comment: Try to clean the DB, and start a dev chain. If you are developing a new chain.

Comment: Indeed I've changed create_runtime_str in lib.rs. Should I keep it as it was or there is a way around to change it too?

Comment: If you want to continue working with the previous one, revert that changes. Otherwise, you could keep the changes and start a new chain.

Comment: I am facing the issue while starting a new chain

Comment: Could you provide more detail? Like, what's your boot command? What changes did you do?